# How to instantiate a singleton

Tags: c++, oop

I want to have one instance of the class `C` in my program, and I defined a singleton method `get_instance` as follows.

```
class C {
    static map<int, map<int, int> > t;
  public:
    static C& get_instance() {
        static C instance;
        return instance;
    }
  private:
    C() {};
};
```

and I tried to get a distance using this method.

```
static C& rt = C.get_instance();
```

However, I am getting an error

```
src/C.cpp:115:41: error: expected primary-expression before ‘.’ token
 static C& rt = C.get_instance();
```

Am I doing something wrong?

The Singleton design is from [C++ Singleton design pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1008019/c-singleton-design-pattern)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should write `C::get_instance()`.

Comment: Thank you. Is it because it's a static method?

Comment: @user2418202 exactly.

Comment: @user2418202: for `static` members you're effectively using the class name as a scoping mechanism (akin to a namespace), and the same `::` notation should be used; whereas for non-static members you're actually doing something with a specific runtime object instance of the class (namely `*this`), and `.` is used for that....